# No connections shown under the Connections window of SQL Developer client

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Connections window is empty. I have tried restarting, reinstalling the sql client, Window>Reset Windows to Factory Settings but still cannot see any connections.
Does anyone know what might the issue be? And how to fix this?

- Client: Oracle SQL Developer
- Version: 19.4.0.354
- OS: Windows 10

[image: Oracle SQL Developer client]

Comment: are you saying you USED to have connections, but now they have disappeared? or are you expecting to see them 'automatically,' somehow?

Comment: I used to have connections and now are not to be seen. Also the Connections group is missing the icons for adding connection, refresh, filter, etc. as can be seen in the attached screenshot above.

Comment: sorry, screenshot was cropped, couldn't tell. look for your connections.json file - go open it in a json editor, see if it's corrupted...if you can fix it. if you can't, delete the file, and you'll have to start over

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - perfect! Indeed the connections.json was corrupt. One of the connections object was missing the "info" object under it.
It is fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! and welcome to stackoverflow!